# Why do Columns not stay hidden after calling DataGridView.Columns.Clear()?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, visibility, datagridviewcolumn

I have seen a lot of posts on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datagridview+columns+visible) about weird behaviour of Columns and their visibility in particular when refreshing the grid and dynamically building the columns in the list, but haven't found a satisfactory solution.

After some digging I am almost certain this issue is due to the use of the `DataGridView.Columns.Clear()` method.

So far I haven't been able to work out why but removing the Clear() method when I dynamically build my DataGridView Columns stops hidden columns from appearing, but I don't understand why this would have any affect? Surely if you clear the Columns collection and use `DataGridView.Columns.Add()` to start adding new ones, code like;

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); // This is the offending method!!

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.ShowEditingIcon = false;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "ID";
col.HeaderText = "ID";
col.Visible = false; // Notice the visibility of this column...
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

... // Code is repeated for other columns in the collection
```

I can't see anything wrong with but if `dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();` is included at the beginning my hidden column becomes visible, surely this is a bug?

Comment: did you try dataGridView1.Invalidate() after adding the columns?

Comment: I did try that a long with `Refresh()` which is more or less the same thing. Behaves the same way...

Comment: The only way I have managed to get around it is to stop dynamically rebuilding my column list which is not ideal (just loading my column creation method once at form load), as I want to show different results with different criteria.

Comment: Have you tried some thing like an empty datatable to your datagridview some thing like `DataTable dtEmpty=new DataTable(); dataGridView1.DataSource = dtEmpty;` or simply `dataGridView1.DataSource = null`;

Comment: I have tried setting `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` but as I'm not using `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;` this has no affect. Plus for reference I'm using Entity Framework with Repository pattern for my data.

Comment: I love how this got down-voted, I provided all the information I could and tried to make the question as clear as possible. A bit of feedback as to what I could have done better would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue. The `Clear` method call is just fine, you can remove columns one by one and the issue still persists. The "offending" call is surprisingly `Add`:

```
col.Visible = false; // Notice the visibility of this column...
if (col.Visible)
{
   // Just to be sure. Never get here.
}
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
if (col.Visible)
{
   // Surprise! We are here.
}
```

**Why this behavior occurs?**

It's definitely a bug. The issue is happening only and only if **all** the following conditions are met:

1. `DataGridView` is in bound mode, i.e. has `DataSource` set. The data source type doesn't matter.
2. `Columns` collection is empty
3. `Add` method is called with a column having `Visible = false`

In this case the code hits an internal class `DataGridViewDataConnection` method `MatchCurrencyManagerPosition`. Take a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewDataConnection.cs,8cd709952d1eda78), especially the

```
// Treat case where columnIndex == -1. We change the visibility of the first column.
```

comment and the code block after that comment.

**How to avoid it**

To recap, this is happening only in data bound mode and only for the first added column if it is set to be hidden.

So there are a couple ways to fix that:

1. Make sure the grid is not in bound mode when repopulating columns

   ```
   var dataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;
   dataGridView.DataSource = null;
   // Repopulate columns
   //...
   dataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
   ```
2. Don't use [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Create all columns and keep them in either variables or temporary list, and at the end use the [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx) method which has no such effect.
3. Do not set `Visible = false` in advance. Create and add all the columns, then hide the desired ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the datatable's `DefaultView` being directly set as gridview's datasource.

We should set datasource property to `DefaultView.ToTable()` because whenever datatable is Cleared or Reset, then it clears metadata and hence loses the visibility information of grid.

Now this is really unidentified why reseting datatable information affects `DataGridViewColumn`'s visibility.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly have a look and see if this helps.

Comment: Coming back to this just because I'm going through my old questions and realised this doesn't help. Reason being the `.Clear()` is called before a rebuild my columns and explicitly set to `Visible = false` before adding it to the `Columns` collection so although the old meta data has gone I'm creating new meta data.