# visual studio c# DataGridView maintain background color after sort

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I populated a DataGridView with a DataTable that contains plain text. Later, I set a specific cell's background color using:

```
grid.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = setColor;
```

This works fine until I click on the column sort button in the DataGridView. I would like to know  if there is a way to maintain the background color after sorting, irrespective of the text value of the cell. Once I set that cell's background color, it will remember that background color after sorting.

I have seen other examples using the

```
CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
```

Event Handler, but the code they write here always seems to have a preconceived notion of what color the cell's background needs to be in relation to the cell's text content (ex: if cellText == "Critical" ...). That will not work in my case, I just need it to remember which cells are set to a specific color.

Any help?

Comment: There is no *maintain color*. If you need something to be maintained (exists after re-creation) you will have to provide a way to store/restore it. To example list of colors for *each row*, which you then can use in formatting or owner-drawing of cells.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that...can you provide an example? Is there a way to take the DataGridView cell in the handler (e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex) and extract which rowIndex and colIndex that cell is associated with the original DataTable?

Comment: You can use invisible (not displayed) column to hold data you need. There is also [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tag.aspx) property in winforms everywhere specially for purpose to hold custom data.

Comment: I tried to use the Tag but it didn't work. All the Tags revert back to null. Is this because, as you said, the cells are being re-created? if(grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag != null)

Comment: How do you populate `DataGridView`? I've never used binding in winforms myself. You may have to set `Tag` in the place where you set initial `BackColor` now. Then `CellFormatting` will have to process your colors assignment (and I expect it will do it after sorting).

Comment: I simply set the DataSource: grid.DataSource = table;... where table is just a DataTable. Also, I did set the tag exactly where I am originally setting the color:             grid.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = setColor;
            grid.Rows[row].Cells[col].Tag = setColor;

Comment: How do you sort data? You have to sort *view*, not original `DataTable` ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/806725/1997232)). Or you have to maintain colors on the `DataTable` level (to example, as 2-dimentional array of colors somewhere).

Comment: I'm not manually sorting anything, I am clicking on the column title of the DataGridView control and it automatically sorts for me. I can try to maintain a separate DataTable just for colors, but my problem is the same as earlier: In the DataGridView's CellFormatting Event Handler, how do I relate the DataGridView's row and column index back to the row and column of the original DataTable? The handler gives me e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex, but that does not match the DataTable's rowIndex and columnIndex. How do I revert the association to extract the original DataTable field?

Comment: Yes, you are right, 2-dimensional array won't work. You need some *key*. Then, obviously, colors should be defined in `DataTable` (as invisible column), see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6359234/1997232) to hide column (I assume your columns are auto-generated, if not, then invisible column is easy). This invisible column is like `Tag` for `DataRow`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "DataBindingComplete" event !

e.g.

```
    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Effective Date"].Value) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
            }
            else { row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had to do (thanks to the pointers from Sinatr) : I had to create a second DataTable that is used solely to keep track of which cells are what colors. Then, I had to add a hidden column to the DataGridView which is used as a key. I put the row number of the DataTable in this field so that after it gets sorted, I can use that row-number key to determine the row index into my Color Table. I added code in the DataGridView's CellFormatting to check the Color Table and reapply the color formatting. To make matters a little more complicated, I was having issues on getting the 1st column to become invisible, so I had to ensure that my hidden column was not the first column.

Overall I feel like these steps were hacks to get around the poorly designed and buggy DataGridView. I can't imagine a scenario where you would want to color a cell, and then have it revert colors after sorting. Sorting, in my mind, is just a rearrangement, NOT changing properties or values. I'm sure DataGridView is great and flexible for so many application, but this seems like a fundamental bug or design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old but the correct way to color DataGridView cells and maintain colors is to use the RowPrePaint event.  That way you don't have to re-process the rows "manually" in any future changes to the DataGridView.

What I do is add additional columns or you can use a separate datatable to hold changes.  Then using this event doing something similar to this:

```
    private void dgvResults_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        bool.TryParse(dgvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["IsChanged"].Value.ToString(), out bool bIsChanged);
        if(bisChanged)
           dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MyCellName"].Style.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
    }
```