# vb.net winforms, what is the e.handled = true equivalent for anything to do with column headers in a dgv?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, formatting, datagridcolumnheader

I have a dgv that is populated with formatted data(backcolor).
Ss soon as a user clicks on one of the headercells to re-order the rows all the formatting disappears.
How can I set the headercells to be unclickable?

I tried e.handled = true, but that does not work as it is not part of the family...

Comment: If that's the case then you're doing it wrong. If you specifically want the data to not be sorted then that's fine but preventing it being sorted because of this is wrong. If you hale the appropriate event and do the colouring there, it will be maintained when sitting occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [visual studio c# DataGridView maintain background color after sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782368/visual-studio-c-sharp-datagridview-maintain-background-color-after-sort)

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`DataGridViewColumn.SortMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode) property to [`NotSortable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode).

```
For i As Integer = 0 To YourDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
    YourDataGridView.Columns(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
Next i
```