# Datagridview shows first column after setting Datasource when all columns are invisible

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, windows

I have a `DataGridView`, I set all columns' visible to false.
Now I set the DataSource, Kaboom, Guess what? The first column is visible. Why is that happening? What's the reason?
Is there a way to prevent this default behaviour or override it with some other action?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359234/datagridview-id-column-will-not-hide See here please,
Hope helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers from the [suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359234/3773066) by B.Yaylaci will help, I feel that they are obscure for future developers maintaining your code - plus, what if you want to make your ID column visible at some point but don't want it displayed last in the columns? A simple approach to correct these issues when altering the `DataSource` is to set column visibility in the `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event for more consistent behavior.

For example, if for some reason I wanted the `DataGridView` to appear completely empty* after binding until I decide otherwise (some kind of logic or user interaction?) then I might do the following:

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        col.Visible = false;
    }

    this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
}
```

<sub>*Note: The `RowHeadersVisible` and `ScrollBars` would need to be reset if columns were later made visible.</sub>